# Output is "NaN"

Tags: java, class, superclass

So, I have developed a class that is suppose to be used by another class.  The class I developed is as follows:

```
public class Car
{
private double milesPerGallon;
private double gas;

//Constructs a car with a given fuel efficiency
public Car(double milesPerGallon)
{
    gas = 0.0;
}

//Increases the amount of gas in the gas tank
public void addGas(double amount)
{
    gas = gas + amount;
}

//Decreases the amount of gas in the gas tank (due to driving and therefore consuming gas)
public void drive(double distance)
{
    gas = gas - (distance / milesPerGallon);
}

//Calculates range, the number of miles the car can travel until the gas tank is empty
public double range()
{
    double range;
    range = gas * milesPerGallon;
    return range;
}
}
```

The class that is suppose to use the class I developed is:

```
public class CarTester
{
/**
 * main() method
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Car honda = new Car(30.0);      // 30 miles per gallon

    honda.addGas(9.0);              // add 9 more gallons
    honda.drive(210.0);             // drive 210 miles

    // print range remaining
    System.out.println("Honda range remaining: " + honda.range());

    Car toyota = new Car(26.0);      // 26 miles per gallon

    toyota.addGas(4.5);              // add 4.5 more gallons
    toyota.drive(150.0);             // drive 150 miles

    // print range remaining
    System.out.println("Toyota range remaining: " + toyota.range());
}
}
```

Both classes compile successfully, however when the program is run I get the output "NaN," which stands for "Not a Number."  I looked this up and supposedly it occurs when there is a mathematical process that attempts to divide by zero or something similar.  I am not, I repeat, not looking for the answer, but a nudge in the right direction about where I might be making my mistake would be much appreciated (I'm sure it's a very small and stupid mistake).  Thanks!

Comment: Without being able to test this quickly, forcefully convert any values to an integer/float.... So this would mean even where your doing toyota.range() ... wrap that as a float/double value.

Comment: Look at your `milesPerGallon` instance variable. Anything wrong?

Comment: Because `honda.milesPerGallon` is 0, because you never set it to anything. (This is why it's important not to give two different things the same name - because it confuses you)

Comment: A good trick is to declare variables you want to be initialized with the constructor `final`.  Then the compiler will tell you if you forgot a step, like you did here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save your `milesPerGallon` variable at constructor:

```
public Car(double milesPerGallon)
{
   this.milesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;
   gas = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see how that works and it outputs the correct answer for the Honda and I created an if-else statement in the range method to output 0.0 if the range is negative (which happens for the Toyota).  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `milesPerGallon` in your `Car` constructor. So it is taking `0.0` as default value. And when a number is divided by `0.0` you're getting `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

`milesPerGallon` needs to be initialized to the constructor parameter.

Constructor:

```
public Car(double milesPerGallon)
{
    this.milesPerGallon = milesPerGallon;
    gas = 0.0;
}
```

milesPerGallon is used later but never initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you did not initialize milesPerGallon. The variable you accept in the constructor is different than the private variable you initialized at the top of your class. Typically people like to use something like public car(aMilesPerGallon) to make sure they know the difference. Or as the answer that was posted while I was typing says, this.milesPerGallon references the variable at the top of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting milesPerGallon in your constructor, thus it is initialized to 0.0. Are you dividing something by that variable somewhere?